# Probability with intersecting normal distributions

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

There are two independent random variables $a$ and $b$, each distributed normally with their own parameters. Given the means and standard deviations for $a$ and $b$, how can I calculate $P(a < b)$?

Comment: Are they independent?

Comment: @DanielLittlewood Yes. Added that in the question. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: Do you know how to find the mean and standard deviation of $a-b$?

Comment: @DavidQuinn No, I'm afraid I'm a bit rusty on this.

Comment: See answer below from Tryss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy if you look for the probability distribution of $a-b$.

As $a \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_a, \sigma_a^2)$ and $b\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_b, \sigma_b^2)$ are independant, you have that

$$a-b = Z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_a-\mu_b, \sigma_a^2+\sigma_b^2)$$

Then you can calculate $P(Z<0)$ as usual

Comment: And the answer is $$\Phi\left(\frac{\mu_b-\mu_a}{\sqrt{\sigma_a^2+\sigma_b^2}}\right).$$